# Can I levitate soon?

Tags: levitation

Whereas I have seen frogs fly in high magnetic fields and Sumo ringers stand on high-temperature superconductors it seems that these are not the only forms of levitation.

Recently a group of physicicsts managed to levitate coffee without a magnetic field ([PNAS link](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2013/07/10/1301860110.full.pdf+html), only [abstract](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2013/07/10/1301860110.abstract) is free though). So while I am still trying to grasp how this is even possible my question is a bit more far fetched:

Can I levitate using this approach?

Comment: Didn't read the link, but is this similar to [acoustic levitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_levitation)?

Comment: Levitate soon? You can levitate *now* using aerodynamic levitation devices referred to as helicopters.

Comment: @Johannes, it makes a difference whether you levitate or you sit on a chair that is tied to a machine that can hover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no, at least not at this point. Unfortunately I was not able to read the entire article, but what I understood from the abstract is that it was only meant for very small volumes and masses, but if they did manage to levitate a cup of coffee, that is a step in the right direction.

But there's another problem with this method - it uses high-intensity sound waves, although I am not sure at exactly what intensity, so it would likely be uncomfortable or possibly even dangerous to levitate a living being in this manner.

Also, I imagine that the device that would be able to levitate the mass of a human with sound waves would be relatively bulky, and there is the factor of the protective equipment that would likely be necessary.

But I do believe it is possible, as just about anything is possible. I just don't think that it is the best way to levitate a human. Other non-living materials, sure, it could be a great thing. But I think there will be better ways to do this with new discoveries. As for if you can levitate soon, who knows. There could be a discovery tomorrow that would allow you to levitate, or it could be years.

UPDATE: I found this bit of information on Wikipedia:

> There is no known theoretical limit to what acoustic levitation can lift given enough vibratory sound, but in practice current technology limits the amount that can be lifted by this force to at most a few kilograms.

This was in the article on Acoustic levitation that Rody posted.